# How to get started with microcontrollers? (ATTINY2313)

Tags: microcontroller

Alright, so I just got an ATTINY2313-2oPI .. But I have no idea how to get started with this thing. Anyone have any tips, or ideas? I just want to get it hooked up, like with a 5V voltage reg. and a USB cable for programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get started with a bare ATTiny2313 you'll need an AVR ICSP, such as [this USB AVR Programmer](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825). You can breadboard the connection from the ICSP cable to the chip (see [ATTiny2313 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2543S.pdf) and [ICSP pinout](https://www.google.com/search?q=icsp%20pinout)). Depending on the programmer used, it may be capable of providing power to the circuit (depending on your needs you wouldn't need to start with a 5V regulator).

Also mentioned in the product page for the programmer is 'avrdude'; basically a free gcc based toolchain for developing and loading code onto Atmel AVR parts (including the attiny family).

In theory an Arduino can also be used for ICSP if you have one laying about, but I'm less familiar with that process.

Comment: Neither the AVR ISP mkII, nor the AVR Dragon programmers provide power to the target without hacking them. I think that the STK500 will though.

Comment: That might be the case; the two I've used (admittedly hobbyist targeted) have had the capability (by switch/jumper) of powering the circuit

Answer (score 1):

I learned it from this page: http://letsmakerobots.com/node/31379 Although it mentions ATtiny13, my first Tiny was a 2313 too.

I love to use an Arduino as ISP, because it gives me the opportunity to experiment with a larger device (ATmega168) which is really easy to program. Then I port the s/w to the Tiny, which isn't too hard either.
Don't go for the Arduino Uno, the ISP s/w doesn't work on that one.

Comment: Supposedly you can use the Uno for ISP, just need a 10uF cap between RESET and GND, I haven't tried it though: http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=30628

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reasonable [single-page tutorial](http://imakeprojects.com/Projects/avr-tutorial/). (It shows using AVR Studio though which you may (or may not) want to bother with if just starting out as opposed to WinAVR / AVR-GCC.)

Here's a page that covers [basic I/O operations](http://iamsuhasm.wordpress.com/tutsproj/avr-gcc-tutorial/) which I found useful.

Other than that [AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=index) has a decent forum dedicated to [just tutorials](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewforum&f=11). I'd check out [Interrrupts](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=89843), [Timers](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=50106&sid=85e47197e847962eb7a8358243d6cff6), and [PWM](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=68302).

Another page I regularly refer to is the [Engbedded Atmel AVR® Fuse Calculator](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc).

Answer (score 1):

[MintyTime](http://www.mintytime.com), a binary clock product I created at [Wicked Device](http://wickeddevice.com), uses an ATTiny2313. You can check out the [Eagle schematics](http://www.mintytime.com/mintytime.sch) to see the basic requirements for wiring it up in a circuit (with an external crystal) and supporting in system program via an ICSP programmer.